# Adding same spfx webpart(no javascript framework) with different configuration, multiple times on the same page replaces the previous webpart output

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, spfx-webparts

I have created a spfx webpart (no javacript framework), it shows member name from active directory.it is working fine if i use once, if i add more than once it replaces the previous output.
here is my code,
[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your render method is rendering a `<div>` with `id="links8"`.  Which means that if there are multiple instances your webpart on the page, then there will multiple div's with the same "links8" ID.

Thus, when your jQuery sets the html of `jQuery("#links8")`, it will update the HTML content of every element on the page with that ID.

So, you need to make sure your `getMembers` is only looking inside your component for a "links8" div instead of looking at the whole page.

First, insert the following as the new first line of your `getMembers` function before the Ajax call:

```
const linksDiv: Element = this.domElement.querySelector('#links8');
```

Then, after you've concatenated your html, use the following to update your div:

```
linksDiv.innerHTML = html;
```

And likewise, change the line in your `else` condition to

```
linksDiv.innerHTML = "No users in the Active Directory Group";
```

Comment: I updated code as you suggested, but may be i have misplaced. so output not showing in webpart.

Comment: if (data.length) {
            jquery.each(data, function (index, item) {
              html += '<li><a class="list-group-item">' + item.displayName + '</a></li>';
            });
            html += "</ul>"
            jquery("#links11").html(html);
            linksDiv.innerHTML = html;
          }
          else {
            //jquery("#links11").html("No Users in the Active Directory Group");
            linksDiv.innerHTML = "No users in the Active Directory Group";
          }
        },

Comment: If you could post your current code in your question, it would be easier to check than in a comment.  It is also better to paste code blocks directly rather than pictures of your code.  In the main stackoverflow.com site they tend to close questions that only include images of their code rather than the text of the code.

Comment: Yeah updated original code, last snip is the "get members" code which you suggested to edit.

Comment: where did `#links11` come from?  your `render()` is creating a div with `id="links8"`.  If the id of the element you are rendering doesn't match what you are using in `const linksDiv: Element = this.domElement.querySelector('#dividhere');`, it will have nothing to display.

Comment: no, in my earlier code i used #links8, now in all the places it is #links11 only. but output not coming still. if you see the, can you check if i have placed the "linksDiv.innerHTML = html;" this statement correctly? or jquery i have commented. will that be an issue?

Comment: is there any solution can be given? any issues in code above?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong that catches my eye, but again, if you posted your code instead of just pictures of you code, we could do some actual troubleshooting.

Comment: I am trying to add my code, but some formatting issue.